# Bootstrap DSC extension for a Azure Arm template

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I have a ARM template which executes a Desired State Configuration extension in order to install and configure IIS. However I need to install and configure some areas which require me to already have other tools installed.

**arm template**

```
{
        "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
        "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "type": "DSC",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "forceUpdateTag":"v.4.2",                                   
            "settings": {                                       
                "wmfVersion": "latest",
                "configuration": {
                    "url": "[concat(variables('dscArtifactsLocation'), '/', variables('dscExtensionArchiveFolder'),'/IISInstall.ps1.zip')]",
                    "script": "IISInstall.ps1",
                    "function": "IISInstall"
                },
                "configurationArguments": {
                    "nodeName": "localhost"
                }
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
                "configurationUrlSasToken": "?TOKEN"
            }
        }
    }
```

**IISInstall.ps1**

```
   Node $nodeName
    { 
        WindowsFeature IIS 
        { 
            Ensure = "Present" 
            Name = "Web-Server"                       
        } 

        WindowsFeature AspNet45
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name= "Web-Asp-Net45"
        }
    }
```

for example i want to be able to use `xWebAdministration` but this requires me to have installed it first before i can call

```
Import-DscResource -ModuleName xWebAdministration
```

Additionally I need to Install IISUrlRewrite v2, the plan is to use chocolately but this also needs installing before I can use it to install programs. Is it possible to "bootstrap" the DSC execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this this functionality isn't currently supported as `scaleset` extensions run in parallel. possibly the preferred option is to implement the bootstrap in a powershell script run via a [custom script extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/templates/201-vmss-custom-script-windows/)

You could create several seperate powershell scripts stored in blobstorage and call them seperated with `&&`
here is an example for adding a new HDD to a scaleset instance via powershell   `before` deploying dotnet.core.

`{
  "name": "[concat(variables('vmNodeTypeAppName'),'_InitializeVM')]",
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "settings": {
      "fileUris": ["https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1"]
    },
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "protectedSettings": {
      "commandToExecute":
        "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command \"Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter F -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel DataDisk -Confirm:$false\" && powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File dotnet-install.ps1 -SharedRuntime"
    },
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension"
  }
}`